# Unwanted duplicating data from one field into several others

Tags: lightning, databinding

I have a form that behaves strangely. The first field is the Name field on the object. The next field is the first required field. When I enter data in it, that same data appears in all the other required fields in the form.

Here I have entered "il1" in "Lender Number" field and it autopopulated into Mailing Address Line 1, etc. If I change the value in any of the connected fields, they all change to the new value!

[image]

It almost looks like an angular Javascript type binding. However, I haven't created any such binding myself. My only guess is that Salesforce and Lightning have done it for me.

Oh, and btw: It only happens for non-system-admin SF users.

Here's the input element for the first required field:

```
<input class="lendernumber cols9 input uiInput uiInputText 
uiInput--default uiInput--input" type="text" aria-describedby=""
placeholder="" required="" id="61:2;a" data-aura-rendered-by="65:2;a"
aria-required="true" autocomplete="off">
```

Here's the input element for the first duplicated field:

```
<input class="mailingaddressline1 cols9 input uiInput uiInputText
uiInput--default uiInput--input" type="text" aria-describedby=""
placeholder="" id="76:2;a" data-aura-rendered-by="80:2;a"
autocomplete="off">
```